# Dynamically add widgets in a cell to represent "tags" in Datagrid

Tags: gwt, datagrid, widget, custom-cell

In a GWT web app, I am using a DataGrid to manage elements from a database. I represent a list of elements as rows, the columns being editable fields of their characteristics (id, name, description). I am mostly using the EditTextCell class.

I now want to create a custom cell, for a column that has to represent a list of "tags" that can be attached to every element. From this cell, tags could be added, using a + button (that makes a drop-down menu appear or something), and deleted. Each tag should be a kind of button, or interactive widget (I later want to display pop-up with info, trigger actions, etc).

Actually, it would not be so different from the "tags" bar on the Stack Overflow website...

[image]

So I have been looking for a solution:

- I thought this would be easy to do. I imagined just putting a FlowPanel in the cell, adding/removing Buttons/Widgets dynamically. But it turns out that in GWT Widgets and Cells and very different objects apparently..
- I read making use of the AbstractCell class to create a custom cell allows to do anything, but its working is very low level and obscure to me.
- I saw that CompositeCell allows to combine various cell widgets into one cell, but I have not found if it is possible to do it dynamically, or if the widgets are going to be the same for all lines throughout a column. I mostly saw examples about, for instance, how to put two Buttons in every cell of a single column.

What is the easiest way to implement what I need?

---

EDIT:

So, after some tests, I am going for Andrei's suggestion and going "low-level", creating a custom cell extending AbstractCell<>. I could create an appropriate "render" function, that generates a list of html "button", and also attaches Javascript calls to my Java functions when triggering a Javascript event (onclick, onmouseover, onmouseout...).

It is working pretty well. For instance, by clicking the "+" button at the end a tag list, it calls a MenuBar widget that presents the list of tags that can be added.

But I am struggling to find a way to update the underlying data when adding a tag.

To sum up:

- I have a CustomData class that represents the data I want to display in each line of the table. It also contains the list of tags as a Set.
- ModelTable (extends DataGrid) is my table.
- CustomCell (extends AbstractCell) can renders the list of tags as several buttons on a line.
- A click on a "+" button in a cell makes a AddTagMenu popup drop down, from which I can click on the tag to add.

[image]

How do I update the content of the cell?

I tried playing around with onBrowserEvent, onEnterKeyDown, bus events... with no success. At best I can indeed add a tag element to the underlying object, but the table is not updated.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to meet your requirements without going really "low-level", as you call it.

It's relatively easy to create a cell that would render tags exactly as you want them. Plus icon is also easy, if this is the only action on the cell. However, it is very difficult to make every tag within a cell an interactive widget, because the DataGrid will not let you attach handlers to HTML rendered within a cell. You will need to supply your own IDs to these widgets, and then attach handlers to them in your code. The problem, however, is that when the DataGrid refreshes/re-renders, your handlers will most likely be lost. So you will have to attach them again to every tag in every cell on every change in the DataGrid.

A much simpler approach is to create a composite widget that represents a "row", and then add these "rows" to a FlowPanel. You can easily make it look like a table with CSS, and supply your own widget that looks like a table header. You will need to recreate some of the functionality of the DataGrid, e.g. sorting when clicked on "column" header - if you need this functionality, of course.

Comment: Thank you Andrei. Would you tell that switching from cell to widgets, hence re-implementing functionalities of tables in a widget, is easier than creating a custom cell implementing AbstractCell?

Comment: Rendering tags within an extended AbstractCell is easy. The problem is with the behavior of tags inside the cell.

Answer (score 1):

As you have already noted, using `CompositeCell` could be a way to get what you want.

The idea is to create a cell for every tag and then (during rendering) decide which one should be shown (rendered). Finally combine all those cells into one by creating a `CompositeCell`.

The main disadvantage of this solution is that you need to know all possible tags before you create a `DataGrid`.

**So, if you have a fixed list of possible tags or can get a list of all existing tags and this list is reasonably small, here is a solution.**

---

First, we need to know which tag is represented by a column so I extended a `Column` class to keep information about a tag. Please, note that `TagColumn` uses `ButtonCell` and also handles `update` when the button is clicked:

```
public class TagColumn extends Column<DataType, String> {
    private TagEnum tag;

    public TagColumn(TagEnum tag) {
        super(new ButtonCell());

        this.tag = tag;

        setFieldUpdater(new FieldUpdater<DataType, String>() {
            @Override
            public void update(int index, DataType object, String value) {
                Window.alert("Tag " + getTag().getName() + " clicked");
            }
        });
    }

    public TagEnum getTag() {
        return tag;
    }

    @Override
    public String getValue(DataType object) {
        return tag.getName();
    }
}
```

Then create a cell for each tag (I have hard-coded all tags in a `TagEnum`):

```
List<HasCell<DataType, ?>> tagColumns = new ArrayList<HasCell<DataType, ?>>();
for(TagEnum tag : TagEnum.values())
    tagColumns.add(new TagColumn(tag));
```

Now, the most important part: decide either to show the tag or not - overwrite `render` method of the `CompositeCell`:

```
CompositeCell<DataType> tagsCell = new CompositeCell<DataType>(tagColumns) {
    @Override
    protected <X> void render(Context context, DataType value, SafeHtmlBuilder sb, HasCell<DataType, X> hasCell) {
        if(value.getTagList().contains(((TagColumn) hasCell).getTag()))
            super.render(context, value, sb, hasCell);
        else
            sb.appendHtmlConstant("<span></span>");
    }
};
```

This is important to always render any element (for example empty `span` when the tag should not be shown). Otherwise the `CompositeCell`'s implemantation will get confused when accessing sibling elements.

---

Finally, full, working example code:

```
private DataGrid<DataType> getGrid() {
    DataGrid<DataType> grid = new DataGrid<DataType>();

    List<HasCell<DataType, ?>> tagColumns = new ArrayList<HasCell<DataType, ?>>();
    for(TagEnum tag : TagEnum.values())
        tagColumns.add(new TagColumn(tag));

    CompositeCell<DataType> tagsCell = new CompositeCell<DataType>(tagColumns) {
        @Override
        protected <X> void render(Context context, DataType value, SafeHtmlBuilder sb, HasCell<DataType, X> hasCell) {
            if(value.getTagList().contains(((TagColumn) hasCell).getTag()))
                super.render(context, value, sb, hasCell);
            else
                sb.appendHtmlConstant("<span></span>");
        }
    };

    Column<DataType, DataType> tagsColumn = new Column<DataType, DataType>(tagsCell) {
        @Override
        public DataType getValue(DataType object) {
            return object;
        }
    };

    grid.addColumn(tagsColumn, "Tags");

    grid.setRowData(Arrays.asList(
            new DataType(Arrays.asList(TagEnum.gwt)), 
            new DataType(Arrays.asList(TagEnum.table, TagEnum.datagrid)), 
            new DataType(Arrays.asList(TagEnum.datagrid, TagEnum.widget, TagEnum.customCell)), 
            new DataType(Arrays.asList(TagEnum.gwt, TagEnum.table, TagEnum.widget, TagEnum.customCell)), 
            new DataType(Arrays.asList(TagEnum.gwt, TagEnum.customCell)), 
            new DataType(Arrays.asList(TagEnum.gwt, TagEnum.table, TagEnum.datagrid, TagEnum.widget, TagEnum.customCell))
        )
    );

    return grid;
}

public class TagColumn extends Column<DataType, String> {
    private TagEnum tag;

    public TagColumn(TagEnum tag) {
        super(new ButtonCell());

        this.tag = tag;

        setFieldUpdater(new FieldUpdater<DataType, String>() {
            @Override
            public void update(int index, DataType object, String value) {
                Window.alert("Tag " + getTag().getName() + " clicked");
            }
        });
    }

    public TagEnum getTag() {
        return tag;
    }

    @Override
    public String getValue(DataType object) {
        return tag.getName();
    }
}

public class DataType {
    List<TagEnum> tagList;

    public DataType(List<TagEnum> tagList) {
        this.tagList = tagList;
    }

    public List<TagEnum> getTagList() {
        return tagList;
    }
}

public enum TagEnum {
    gwt         ("gwt"),
    table       ("table"),
    datagrid    ("datagrid"),
    widget      ("widget"),
    customCell  ("custom-cell");

    private String name;

    private TagEnum(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello Adam. Thank you very much for your answer. I test this idea, but I see two problems with it:
 - The number of possible tags might actually grow quite big. Several dozens for sure, several hundreds maybe. And the table might have to display hundreds of lines at one. So I will need to see how it behaves.
 - The possible tags are fixed, but in a database, and some users can create new tags. So I cannot use an Enum. But I guess I could work around that.

Comment: This solution does not require a fixed list of tags. It does not matter if there are thousands of tags in a database - all you need to know is the list of possible tags in the table that you render. In other words, you can replace `for (TagEnum tag : TagEnum.values())` with `for (String tag : tagsOnThisPage)`